# Some questions about localizable push payload content

Tags: ios

In the apple documentation for pushes they give the following example payload

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "loc-key" : "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT",
            "loc-args" : [ "Jenna", "Frank"]
        },
        "sound" : "chime.aiff"
    },
    "acme" : "foo"
}
```

Described as

> The following payload uses the loc-key to specify a localized string
>   in the app’s Localizable.strings file. That string is displayed as the
>   message of the alert. The loc-args contains values to substitute into
>   the string before displaying it.

There is nothing in the "loc-key" or "loc-args" to indicate if this for the title, subtitle or message, so how does the substitution get applied?

How would this payload be extended to apply the same principle to the push alert title, and subtitle, and body, so that all three have their content pulled from the Localizable.strings file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification)

You have loc-key which is the body part, also you have title-loc-key and subtitle-loc-key. If you use these keys once when the messages are received the keys will be changed with the values from Localizable.strings files.

This is an example:

```
{
   "aps" : {
      "alert" : {
         "loc-key" : "KEY",
         "title-loc-key" : "MY_TITLE_KEY",
         "subtitle-loc-key" : "MY_SUBTITLE_KEY"
      }
   }
}
```

As an additional explanation, loc-args, title-loc-args and subtitle-loc-args are used for such cases:

You want to localize string which says how much points you get in the title of the notification.

you need such row in your strings file:

```
...
"wining_notification_title_key" = "You won %@ points";
...
```

And then int notification will be:

```
{
   "aps" : {
      "alert" : {
         "title-loc-key" : "wining_notification_title_key",
         "title-loc-args" : ["5"]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. If a service extension was used, could the content of the notification then just push added by that dynamically and so no need for the payload to contain any localization keys at all?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get that correctly, but yes you can handle the notification and change the content before to show it.

Comment: What I meant was suppose the push payload does not contain a "subtitle" key/value pair. Can the service extension still add dynamically a subtitle into the notifcation that the user sees? But I guess this is straying off tangent into another question, probably better to post a separate one.

Comment: I didn’t try it with service extension, but I’m sure you can modify the notification before to be shown. But you need to add one specific key. You can search for silent push notifications.